# Is there better way to create checkboxes and radio buttons in php form?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, checkbox, radio-button

I have tried an easy way to create checkboxes as well as radio buttons in any php form. Only thing is I am using Codeigniter MVC framework.

Here is the function definition that you can insert in your common-model or any helper file.

```
function createOptions($fieldName, $labelsArray=array(), $selectedOption, $fieldType,$valuesArray = array()) {
        $returnString = '';
        if(count($valuesArray)!=count($labelsArray))
            $valuesArray=$lebelsArray;
        if ($fieldType === 'checkbox') {
            for ($i=0;$i<count($labelsArray);$i++) {
                $returnString.='&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name=' . $fieldName.' value='.$valuesArray[$i].' id='.$valuesArray[$i];
                if(in_array($valuesArray[$i], $selectedOption)){
                        $returnString.=' checked="checked" ';
                }
                $returnString.=' />&nbsp&nbsp<label>'.$labelsArray[$i].'</label>';
            }
        }
        if ($fieldType === 'radio') {
            for ($i=0;$i<count($labelsArray);$i++) {
                $returnString.='&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name=' . $fieldName.' value='.$valuesArray[$i].' id='.$valuesArray[$i];
                if($valuesArray[$i]== $selectedOption)
                        $returnString.=' checked="checked" ';
                $returnString.=' /><label>'.$labelsArray[$i].'</label>';
            }
        }
        return $returnString;
    }
```

And, you have to call this function in view file as,

```
<?php
echo $this->common_model->createOptions('userHobbies[]', $hobbyOptions, $userHobbies, 'checkbox'); ?>
```

First parameter is name of checkbox field or radio field, which is always gonna be same for all options for both cases. Second is labels array, Third is selected options which will show those options as checked while loading the form. Fourth is type of field that will be a string as 'checkbox' or 'radio'. Fifth will be values array, which, if present, will contain values for labels in the same order as that of labels. If its absent, labels array will be teated as values array.
I want to know is there any further optimization in this code possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to here.

`$selectedOption` can now either be a string or array, but is automatically cut to 1 size for radio boxes.

You had some code duplication for either input type so they've been combined and worked a little to fit.

My question to you is, do you really need to abstract the creation of html elements out this hard?

Also, something I should note is that you subscribed to multiple coding standards (1 liner if statements bouncing between using braces and not using braces, etc). It doesn't technically matter which you use, but try to stick with one or the other.

```
function createOptions($fieldName, $labelsArray=array(), $selectedOption, $fieldType, $valuesArray = array()) {
    $returnString = '';
    $selectedOption = (array) $selectedOption;

    if(count($valuesArray) != count($labelsArray))
        $valuesArray = $labelsArray;

    if ($fieldType === 'radio')
        $selectedOption = array_slice($selectedOption, 0, 1);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($labelsArray); $i++)
    {
        $returnString .= sprintf('&nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="%s" name="%s" value="%s" id="%s"',
            $fieldType, $fieldName, $valuesArray[$i], $valuesArray[$i]);

        if(in_array($valuesArray[$i], $selectedOption))
                $returnString .= ' checked="checked" ';

        $returnString .= ' />&nbsp&nbsp<label>'.$labelsArray[$i].'</label>';
    }

    return $returnString;
}
```

Comment: Yes, actually I tried this code after I created a form for getting user information that included user hobbies as checkbox field and user gender as radio field. So I found this way better for dynamically creating these fields. Your code is also better.

Comment: castis, sorry, but I could not get which coding standard u r talking about, I am using netbeans editor's "formatting" facility (Alt+Shift+F).